# Checking if the web appication is started/browsed for the first time in current date

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to find out if my web app is started for the first time. I need to check it on daily basis so that i could send reminder emails.As soon as my app is browsed for the first time the mails should be sent.How to check it? Help Me..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Use a database, to flag that. That for today you have send your emails... and trigger it on your default page, on page load

Comment: But firstly i need to check if my application is started for the first time on current date.How and where to check that?

Comment: You need to use database and Global.aspx page you can check in Application_Start event for every day

Answer (score 0):

The best option for you is to create a database backend. You might even already have one to store user information.

Once you have that, you'll want to utilize the `Page_Load` event on either each individual page, or a master page if you have one. In that, you can update your database with the latest login time for the current user (or in this case, likely, the latest page view--you'll want to be wary of "remember me" situations if you're dealing with logins--and send your email as appropriate.